# Is triple-CRC-32 a bad (or not) idea for generating a uniform distribution hash?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, crc, algorithm-design, bijection

I have an input of 288 bits (comprising 4 × 32-bit and 10 × 16-bit integers). I need to hash this to 96 bits with as few collisions as possible.

I'm aware that CRC is a bijective hash, thus ensuring 100% even distribution (as I understand it). In my view, I should be able to run 3 parallel CRC paths through the input, resulting in a 96-bit hash of optimum distribution.

However, I'm also aware that CRC is not used for such applications. An algorithm such as MetroHash would typically be used.

Could someone explain to me why CRC is a bad (or not) idea for this application?

Note: This is **not** intended for anything secure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) not crypto (or programming).

Comment: For anyone interested in this question: see [this repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617560/is-triple-crc-32-a-bad-or-not-idea-for-generating-a-non-secure-uniform-distrib) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. The identity function is also a bijection. That doesn't make it a good hash in any way.
2. If a function reduces input size, how can it be a bijection?
3. If you are not intending anything secure maybe this is the wrong place to ask. ;)
4. Maybe a more useful answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315172/distribution-of-crc-checksums).

Comment: You are right... this isn't the correct place to ask. I'll repeat the question on SO. CRC-32 is bijective for a 32-bit I/O. Reducing size obviously cannot be bijective ;). Bijection simply indicates distribution, which is the basis of my question.